# Proguard not keeping class although it says so

Tags: java, proguard

I'm trying to keep proguard from renaming/optimizing classes which have a certain annotaion. There are quite a few examples out there and it should be straight forward but proguard isn't behaving as I would expect it to be.

### Issue

Proguard `v6.2.2` obfuscates classes annotated with `@KeepClass` although `-whyareyoukeeping` shows `test.KeepMe is kept by a directive in the configuration`.
I can reproduce the issue with a simple 3 file project.

Proguard config:

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizationpasses 3
-allowaccessmodification

-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

-keep public class test.Entry {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keep @proguard.annotation.KeepClass public class * {
    *;
}

-whyareyoukeeping class test.KeepMe
```

Class which should be kept:

```java
import proguard.annotation.KeepClass;

@KeepClass
public class KeepMe
{
}
```

Proguard log:

```
Explaining why classes and class members are being kept...
Printing usage to [D:\Development\Projects\ProguardTest\build\usage.txt]...

test.KeepMe
  is kept by a directive in the configuration.

Removing unused program classes and class elements...
  Original number of program classes: 3
  Final number of program classes:    2
```

And finally the files in the processed jar file:

```
- test
   |- Entry.class
   |- a.class (Obfuscated KeepMe class)
```

If however I explicitly list the class in the proguard configuration using

```
-keep class test.KeepMe{*;}
```

proguard reports the same log output but the class is untouched (as expected)

Am I missing something or is this a bug in proguard?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the issue was actually related to a bug in proguard. After trying the latest beta it's working as expected.